# How to get the average with intervals?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, average

So I have a dataset of monthly stock returns from January 2000 until today for six different stock indices. At the bottom of the page, I want to show the return across the year as a percentage. When I typed '=average(B8:B19)' on excel it correctly gave me the average for the year 2000, but when I dragged it down it gave me the average for February 2000 to January 2001. Is there any way to create a formula such that when the first cell calculates the average for January 2000 to December 2000, the second cell calculates January 2001 to December 2001, third cell calculates January 2002 to December 2002 etc? So I don't have to manually type the cell ranges for each year and avoid human error.

I have attached an image of my dataset, if anyone could write the excel input or help me figure out how to write it I would appreciate it very much! The average for 2000 would show in cell b256, 2001 in b257 etc

[image: Picture of data]

[image: Picture of table I am hoping to fill]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` in ordinary formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A29=YEAR($A$2:$A$25))*$B$2:$B$25)/SUMPRODUCT(--(A29=YEAR($A$2:$A$25)))
```

or `AVERAGE` + `IF` in array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(A29=YEAR($A$2:$A$25),$B$2:$B$25))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much!